Trying to pass field value from controller into iframe on LWC
Trying to pass Opportunity.AccountId into the url string in an iframe on a lightning web component that I want to sit on opportunity record lightning pages.
I'm new to coding so trying to use this as an opportunity to learn.
I've followed instructions I've seen on a few blogs, but keep getting an error (included below). Why is my controller file giving me an error? What do I need to change?
I was successful in doing this on the account record, just using the {!v.recordid} but doing this on the opp while getting AccountId from the opp is giving me the below error. What am I doing wrong?
controller:
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

import ACCOUNTID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/opportunity.accountId";
import ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/opportunity.Account_Text_Name__c";

const fields = [ACCOUNTID_FIELD, ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD];

export default class SigmaPricingCalcLWC_OPPO extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields })
    opportunity;

      renderedCallback() {
    console.log(this.opportunity.data);
  }
    
    get accountid() {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.accountId, ACCOUNTID_FIELD);
    }

    get account_name() {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.Account_Text_Name__c, ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD);
    }

}
    })

cmp:
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
        <iframe src="{!'https://app.sigmacomputing.com/embed/1-3RPcAQFDd7zewah36T8bIo?account-id=' + accountid}" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="700px"></iframe>
</aura:component>

Error:
Failed to save SigmaPricingCalcLWC_OPPOController.js: Failed to parse CONTROLLER for js://c.SigmaPricingCalcLWC_OPPO: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ':' [2, 26]: Source

You are getting a compile error. Your controller code is for an LWC, but your markup is for an Aura component.
LWC is Salesforce's newest web framework. Aura is the previous framework.
{!v.recordid} notation is valid in Aura components, but not LWC. <aura:component></aura:component> isn't a valid LWC since it's XML and not html.
Your .cmp file should be an html file that's wrapped with
<template>
    
</template>

But you will also need to change all your Aura component code over to LWC.
If you're using LWCs, you would want to build your URL using a LWC getter method. In your controller, your getter would look something like
get srcUrl() {
    return `https://example.com?account-id=${accountid}`;
}

Then in your markup, you can use your getter -
<template>
    <iframe src={urlSrc}></iframe>
</template>

This is the LWC way to do things.
